# Batch- Issues with Changing Variables/Booleans

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I am making a Batch RPG and currently I'm trying to create a shop where you can
buy weapons and stuff. I want to make it so that if the player has enough gold (gld) that they can buy the weapon and it changes the weapon's boolean to true and takes away 20 gold from the gld variable. What am I doing wrong? It doesn't subtract the gold or change to boolean to true.

Here is the code:

```
set /p sword="Enter your selected sword number:"
if %sword%==1 if %gld% GEQ 20 set /a sword1 EQU true 
if %sword%==1 if %gld% GEQ 20 set /a gld EQU %gld%-20
if %sword%==1 if %gld% LSS 20 echo You don't have enough gold!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the `set` command correctly.

```
set /p sword="Enter your selected sword number:"
if %sword%==1 if %gld% GEQ 20 set sword1=true 
if %sword%==1 if %gld% GEQ 20 set /a gld-=20
if %sword%==1 if %gld% LSS 20 echo You don't have enough gold!
```

You can also make one `if` `else` statement to do the same thing

```
set /p sword="Enter your selected sword number:"
if %sword%==1 if %gld% GEQ 20 (
    set sword1=true 
    set /a gld-=20
)  else (
    echo You don't have enough gold!
)
```